# python exception going to wrong except block

Tags: python, exception

I have specified specific exception in different `except` block, but when I raise `exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound` it goes to wrong `except` block (i.e it goes  to `TransportError except` block.

I have this code :

```
  import exchangelib
  try:
    #some code
    raise exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound

  except exchangelib.errors.TransportError:
    print("transport error caught")
  except exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound:
    print("folder not found caught")
  except Exception as e:
    print("exception caught")
```

but when I move the `ErrorFolderNotFound` except block above the `TransportError` block it goes to the right block (i.e `ErrorFolderNotFound` except block)

```
 import exchangelib
  try:
    #some code
    raise exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound

  except exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound:
    print("folder not found caught")
  except exchangelib.errors.TransportError:
    print("transport error caught")

  except Exception as e:
    print("exception caught")
```

**Why is this behavior occurring ,as I am giving specific exception in the `except` block ?**.

Also if any other exception occurs which belong to the same family of **exchangelib**, it goes to except block which already has some specific **exchangelib** error defined in the `except` block, it should go to `except block of Exception

Here in below code , when error is raised ,it goes to `TransportError` except block, but logically it should go to **Exception except block**

```
import exchangelib
try:
#some code
raise exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound

except exchangelib.errors.TransportError:
  print("transport error caught")

except Exception as e:
  print("exception caught")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the hierarchy of the Exceptions in `exchangelib.errors`, I can only guess that `ErrorFolderNotFound` inherits from `TransportError`. I.e.,

```
class MyBaseError(BaseException):
    pass

class TransportError(MyBaseError):
    pass

class ErrorFolderNotFound(TransportError):
    pass

try:
    #some code
    raise ErrorFolderNotFound

except TransportError:
    print("transport error caught")
except ErrorFolderNotFound:
    print("folder not found caught")
except Exception as e:
    print("exception caught")
```

which will print out `transport error caught`

If we change the hierarchy so that `ErrorFolderNotFound` *does not* inherit from `TransportError`. I.e.,

```
class MyBaseError(BaseException):
    pass

class TransportError(MyBaseError):
    pass

class ErrorFolderNotFound(MyBaseError):
    pass

try:
    #some code
    raise ErrorFolderNotFound

except TransportError:
    print("transport error caught")
except ErrorFolderNotFound:
    print("folder not found caught")
except Exception as e:
    print("exception caught")
```

then we'll get `folder not found caught`

Comment: Definitely this, with an intermediate class, see https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/exchangelib/errors.py : `class ResponseMessageError(TransportError):` then `class ErrorFolderNotFound(ResponseMessageError):`